# How to get the result of "all pages with prefix" using Wikipedia api?

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I wish to use Wikipedia api to extract the result of this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:PrefixIndex

When searching "something" on it, for example this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3APrefixIndex&prefix=tal&namespace=4

Then, I would like to access each of the resulting pages and extract their information.

What api call might I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `list=allpages` and specify `apprefix`. For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=allpages&apprefix=tal&aplimit=max

This query will give you the id and title of each article that starts with `tal`. If you want to get more information about each page, you can use this list as a [generator](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Generators):

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&generator=allpages&gapprefix=tal&gaplimit=max&prop=info

You can give different values to the `prop` parameter to get different information about the page.