# Setting "an informative User-Agent string" in getURL

Tags: r, wikipedia-api

I am trying to access a Wikipedia page so to get a list of pages, and get the following error:

```
library(RCurl)
u <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3APrefixIndex&prefix=tal&namespace=4"
getURL(u)
[1] "Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.\n"
```

I hope to get to that page through the Wikipedia api, but [I am not sure it would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056497/how-to-get-the-result-of-all-pages-with-prefix-using-wikipedia-api).

And the thing is that other pages are read without problem, for example:

```
u <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Talk"
getURL(u)
```

Any suggestions?

Side note: In general I would rather to not scrape wiki pages and go through the api, but I fear that this specific pages are not yet available through the api...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [the documentation of `RCurl`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/RCurl.pdf), you can specify additional header by adding a `httpheader` parameter:

```
getURL(u, httpheader = c('User-Agent' = "Informative string with your contact info"))
```